# How to define interfaces in TypeScript to pass the props correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-props

I have a simple component which renders a logo text

```
interface AppBarLogoProps = {
  logo: string;
};

export const AppBarLogo: FC<AppBarLogoProps> = ({ logo }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        {logo}
      </h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

and the AppBarTop component which is more complex than below, but the idea is that I want to pass the logo prop from AppBarTop  to AppBarLogo.

The problem is that I have to use logo.logo notation. How should I define interfaces to use `return <AppBarLogo logo={logo} />` instead of `return <AppBarLogo logo={logo.logo} />` ?

```
interface AppBarTopProps {
  logo: AppBarLogoProps;
}

export const AppBarTop: FC<AppBarTopProps> = ({ logo }) => {
   return <AppBarLogo logo={logo.logo} />
}
```

Comment: your answer is good, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TypeScript intersection `&`:

```
interface AppBarLogoProps {
  logo: string;
};

interface AppBarTopProps {
  foo: string
}

export const AppBarTop: React.FC<AppBarTopProps & AppBarLogoProps> = ({ logo, foo }) => {
  return <AppBarLogo logo={logo} />
}
```

Also, you should probably [not use `FC`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) and simply use function:

```
export const AppBarTop2 = ({ logo, foo }: AppBarTopProps & AppBarLogoProps) => {
  return <AppBarLogo logo={logo} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
interface AppBarTopProps extends AppBarLogoProps {
    // other properties
}

export const AppBarTop: FC<AppBarTopProps> = (props) => {
   return <AppBarLogo {...props} />
}
```

Comment: ok, but if I have 3 interfaces like AppBarLogoProps such as: AppBarLogoProps, AppBarLinks, AppBarButtons can I extend 3 interfaces ?

Comment: without intermediate interface - no. You can also use type s there "type AppBarTopProps = AppBarLogoProps & OtherProps.". So technically it is doable, but you can face a problem in future - what if some of your components will have the property with the same name?